# How to send a access token into the j_security_check using form authentication?

Tags: java, jboss

I am Using Jboss form based Authentication J_security_check. Now I need to use the implicit grant in my application. I want to use both the authentication available based on the user. (custom)

I can get the access token in the callbackUri, Now,  I want the access_token to be sent to the J_security_check by passing through the form. Is there a way to send the token into the request header and capture it inside the j_security_check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add headers with a normal HTML form submit. But you can use AJAX to send a custom POST call.

E.g. using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "j_security_check",
     headers: {
            'X-access_token': 'value1'
        },
     data: { j_username: "John", j_password: "Boston" }
    })
```

On the server side, there's usually a Servlet Filter or JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter or other interceptor that intercepts the access token and translates it into something your security configuration can handle.

See e.g. http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/keycloak/keycloak-oauth2-example-with-rest-application

Comment: Thank you.. But is there a way we can retrieve it in the backend using the usernameloginModule?

Comment: I don't think you can use the usernamePasswordLoginModule for that. You need a security setup with request filters that recognize the access tokens.